# How to limit the number of results in a FetchRequest in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

How can I limit the size of the retrieved `FetchedResults` when making a `FetchRequest` to CoreData?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var fetchRequest:FetchRequest<Kana>

    init(){
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Kana>(entity: Kana.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "alphabet == %@", "hiragana"))
    }

    var body: some View {
        List{
            Text("10 Kanas")
            // Display 10 Kanas
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create `FetchRequest` with `NSFeatchRequest` using corresponding initialiser, as shown below

```
init() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Kana> = Kana.fetchRequest()
    request.fetchLimit = 10
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "alphabet == %@", "hiragana")
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Kana>(fetchRequest: request)
}
```