# How to limit the number of returned records using CloudKit framework?

Tags: database, swiftui, cloudkit

Is there any way to limit the number of records returned from a query using CloudKit framework? E.g. only return the latest value by sorting it by date (already figured that out) but then limit the returned records to 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451047/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a [`CKQueryOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation) and it's [`resultsLimit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation/1515078-resultslimit) property.

> **resultsLimit**
>
> The maximum number of records to return at one time.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> For most queries, leave the value of this property as the
> default value, which is the maximumResults constant. When using that
> value, CloudKit returns as many records as possible while minimizing
> delays in receiving those records. If you want to process a fixed
> number of results, change the value of this property accordingly.