# How to access result on FetchRequest

Tags: swift, core-data

Following [How to limit the number of results in a FetchRequest in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450734/how-to-limit-the-number-of-results-in-a-fetchrequest-in-swiftui) I created a FetchRequest to get the latest billing number.

My code looks like this

```
var billNo: FetchRequest<Payments>
...
init() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Payments> = Payments.fetchRequest()
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "rechnungsNummer", ascending: false)]
    billNo = FetchRequest<Payments>(fetchRequest: request)
}
```

But how on earth do I get access to the values of `billNo.rechnungsNummer`? `billNo.wrappedValue.first?.rechnungsNummer` ist always `nil`.

Or has it all changed the last two years?

btw: it's all inside a view. ;)

Comment: changes in `request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Payments.rechnungsNummer, ascending: false)]`doesn't make it better.

Comment: You have to call `fetch` on the managed object context to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to vadian for the missing hint.

Here's my working code:

```
@FetchRequest var billNo: FetchedResults<Payments>
...
init() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Payments> = Payments.fetchRequest()
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "rechnungsNummer", ascending: false)]
    _billNo = FetchRequest<Payments>(fetchRequest: request)
}
```

And in body, I can access this easily with

```
billNo.first?.rechnungsNummer
```

I hope it might help other beginners like me. :-)